# Redis maxmemory on ElastiCache instance lower than expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have an AWS ElastiCache instance hosted on a `cache.m5.xlarge` instance type, which advertises `12.93gb` of ram.

from the [AWS ElastiCache documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html#ParameterGroups.Redis.NodeSpecific) it says that a `cache.m5.xlarge` instance should have its `maxmemory` set to `13891921715`, which divided by 1024*1024*1024 equals roughly `12.94gb`.

However, we recently found out that our server is evicting keys based upon the `maxmemory-policy: volatile-lru` configuration when hitting roughly `9.7gb`.

Upon inspecting the actual maching using `redis-cli` and issuing a `info memory` command, we get:

```
my-stack.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379> info memory
# Memory
used_memory:10070155984
used_memory_human:9.38G
used_memory_rss:10629488640
used_memory_rss_human:9.90G
used_memory_peak:10419154184
used_memory_peak_human:9.70G
used_memory_peak_perc:96.65%
used_memory_overhead:581297150
used_memory_startup:3668736
used_memory_dataset:9488858834
used_memory_dataset_perc:94.26%
allocator_allocated:10073929632
allocator_active:10463571968
allocator_resident:10660438016
used_memory_lua:60416
used_memory_lua_human:59.00K
used_memory_scripts:1032
used_memory_scripts_human:1.01K
number_of_cached_scripts:4
maxmemory:10418941287
maxmemory_human:9.70G
maxmemory_policy:volatile-lru
allocator_frag_ratio:1.04
allocator_frag_bytes:389642336
allocator_rss_ratio:1.02
allocator_rss_bytes:196866048
rss_overhead_ratio:1.00
rss_overhead_bytes:-30949376
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.06
mem_fragmentation_bytes:559163408
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:1048576
mem_clients_slaves:49806
mem_clients_normal:6528840
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

The biggest point I see here is `maxmemory:10418941287`, which is about `3.2gb` less than expected.

Our server configuration is setup with replication, so in total we have two `cache.m5.xlarge` nodes.

Why is there the dependency between the actual server's `maxmemory` setting and what the documentation is saying, and is there any way to use more of the server's memory for actual cached items?

Comment: Is the advertised RAM purely for data storage, or does it include the overhead of the operating system and software?

Comment: I assume the advertised amount is the amount of RAM available to the underlying virtual machine (and not 100% usable by redis), however I'm mostly concerned about the `maxmemory` value that differs from what the documentation states

Comment: What's your `reserved-memory` setting? It gets added on top of the 9.7GB, so maybe you have it at something like 3.2 GB (12.9 - 9.7)